# Laravel 5.5 live on shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5, server

This is my first project on laravel project is completed I want to deploy my files on shared hosting. I copied all my files on the server and copy the public folder on the root directory. It shows me white blank page.

Note: The file are uploaded as sub domains.

Comment: Here is the link of the website: http://tafreehtv.com/awesome-project/

Comment: turn on display_error like this and maybe you get an error [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: nothing change. I checked my error log file it also show nothing relevant.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit the index.php and add at first line

```
echo 'test';exit;
```

if it works then try to edit the error reporting in the php ini

Comment: still got the blank page.